# WPF: TabControl & DataTemplates

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, tabcontrol

I just want to understand the following scenario. Where I am implementing a `<TabControl>` bound to a `ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>`

**No Data Templates**

When I don't have any `DataTemplate`s, the text `WpfApplication1.TabViewModel` appears in the Tab Header and Content. Ok I understand this part.

**Just `ItemTemplate`**

When I just have

```
<TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabTitle}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Then my tab header is filled. The tab content is still `WpfApplication1.TabViewModel`.

**Just `DataTemplate`**

When I just have the below in my `<Window.Resources>`

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TabViewModel}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

That templates fills up the tab header.

**Both**

When I have both, the `ItemTemplate` fills up the Tab Header while the `DataTemplate` fills up the tab content. Why all this difference. `ItemTemplate` & `DataTemplate` fills up the tab header if the other is not present. If both are present, `ItemTemplate` fills up the header while `DataTemplate` fills the content.

Though I have things working, I am quite confused. Shouldn't something like `<TabControl.HeaderTemplate>` be what fills the header and `<TabControl.ItemTemplate>` fill up the content?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

First of all, there are two templates involved here:

- `TabControl.ItemTemplate`, used to render the `TabItem` headers
- `TabControl.ContentTemplate`, used to render the `TabItem` contents

If you don't set these properties explicitly then WPF will attempt to resolve them elsewhere. It will walk up the logical tree looking for a resource telling it how to render your view model. If it finds a `DataTemplate` that has a matching `DataType` but no key, it will use it to render the view model. If it doesn't find one, it'll default to rendering the `ToString` value of the object.

So, if you want to be explicit, you want something like this:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabTitle}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Since you're not being specific, WPF is attempting to walk up your logical tree to find an appropriate `DataTemplate`. When it finds it, it uses it to render the view model. Where it doesn't find it, it calls `ToString` and renders that.

So to address your specific cases:

**Just ItemTemplate**

You've explicitly stated how to render tab headers but not tab contents. So the former is rendered using the provided `DataTemplate`, but the latter will default to `ToString`.

**Just DataTemplate**

You've not explicitly stated how to render either tab headers or tab contents. Therefore, WPF searches for an appropriate `DataTemplate` for both. Since both contain an instance of your view model (that's their `DataContext`) then the same `DataTemplate` will be used to render tab headers and their contents.

NOTE: you didn't explicitly state that this is what's happening in your question. Correct me if I'm wrong.

**Both**

In this case, you've explicitly stated how to render tab headers but not tab contents. Therefore, the explicit `DataTemplate` is used for tab headers and the implicit `DataTemplate` is used for tab contents.

Comment: If i want the list box with the content and tab control item source will have the item list for the list box..What can i do for this? List box also have data template with it self

Comment: "First of all, there are two templates involved here..." Argh! You'd think that the way you specify a TabItem outside of a DataTemplate works the same in a TabControl ItemTemplate property, since ListView et al. work this way. Thanks!